# How to avoid Java from auto ending lines?

Tags: java

```
class Hi {
public static void main(String []args){
    if(args.length ==0)
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    else
            System.out.println("Hello ");
            for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
            System.out.println(args[i] + " ");
            }
         }
}
```

Hi, I have a very simple program. If I run it like this: java Hi Robin Hood
I wish to get an output of only 1 line like this:

Hello Robin Hood

But instead I'm getting:

Hello

Robin

Hood

Can anyone please teach me how to make the desired output? Thank you

Comment: ln = line. Try `.print`. Or build the string using a StringBuilder and print once

Comment: Didn't know it was so simple, I'm sorry for a stupid question. Thank you so much!

Comment: Give a man a fish and he will eat for a day. Teach a man to fish and he will eat for the rest of his life. => you need to know where to find these informations : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html (for the String class), and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html (for the whole javadoc)

Comment: You should do some (any) research before posting. Listen to @chburd :)

Comment: Also you can use `Arrays.toString(args);`

Comment: yes i did google abit about it but I got results about JTextArea which are much more confusing for me, thanks guys! Please pardon me I'm a beginner

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
System.out.print("Hello ");
```

and

```
System.out.print(args[i] + " ");
```

in the loop

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.print("This is on ");
System.out.println("one line.");
System.out.print("This is the ");
System.out.println("next line.");
```

Output:

```
This is on one line.
This is on the next line.
```

Good luck! :)